# create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given? Django

Tags: python, django, cleaned-data

I was confused to why when I run this code it returns an error

> create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
if request.method == "POST":
my_form = RawProductCreateForm(request.POST)
if my_form.is_valid():
    Product.objects.create(my_form.cleaned_data)
```

but when I modify on the create method and add ** before passing the cleaned data it works!

```
Product.objects.create(**my_form.cleaned_data)
```

Comment: post the model and the form too

Comment: Read the docs on `objects.create`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#create It only takes keyword arguments in the form of `model_prop=value` and no positional arguments. The `**` operator in python applies the dictionary as keyword arguments to the function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters.

Comment: If your `RawProductCreateForm` is a `ModelForm`, you could use [the save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) to create the Product object e.g. `my_form.save()`

Answer (score 11):

It is because `create` takes keyword arguments, like

```
    Product.objects.create(product_name="Dish Soap", product_price=73)
```

Placing the `**` before it tells the model to treat `my_form.cleaned_data` as a dictionary of keyword arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The create function under the hood looks more less like this:

```py
def create(self, **data):
   pass
```

As you can see you have one positional argument `self`, other one is just a key words dictionary. When you call this function like this:

```py
Product.objects.create(my_form.cleaned_data)
```

You are passing two positional arguments one is `objects` this is how python handle classes and methods and other one is `my_form.cleaned_data`, but the function exptes only one positional and any numbers of named arguments.
In second call:

```py
Product.objects.create(**my_form.cleaned_data)
```

lets say the `my_form.cleaned_data` looks like this:

```
{ 
  'age': 1,
  'name': 'good product'
}
```

so the equvialent of the second call would be

```py
Product.objects.create(name='good product', age=1)
```

As you can see you have only one positional argument `objects` and 2 named arguments.
In create function you can refer to data like this:

```py
def create(self, **data):
   name = data['name']
   age = data['age']
```

Comment: so passing the cleaned_data with ** tells the function to treat cleaned_data as kwarg right ?

Comment: Correct. In simpler words it converts dictionary to named arguments

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to insert data without a point to the field defined in the model.
To fix this you have to pass field name inside the `create()` with assignment operator.

```
Product.objects.create(field1="<field 1 data>", field2=<field2 data>)
```